# sqlalchemy: previous row and next row by id

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a table Images with `id` and `name`. I want to query its previous image and next image in the database using `sqlalchemy`. How to do it in only one query?

```
sel = select([images.c.id, images.c.name]).where(images.c.id == id)
res = engine.connect().execute(sel)

#How to obtain its previous and next row?
...
```

Suppose it is possible that some rows have been deleted, *i.e.*, the `id`s may not be continuous. For example,

```
Table: Images
------------
id | name
------------
1  | 'a.jpg'
2  | 'b.jpg'
4  | 'd.jpg'
------------
```

Answer (score 10):

```
prev_image = your_session.query(Images).order_by(Images.id.desc()).filter(Images.id < id).first()

next_image = your_session.query(Images).order_by(Images.id.asc()).filter(Images.id > id).first()
```

Comment: If you need to use this with datetime instead of id, read this
https://gist.github.com/danielthiel/8374607
SQLAlchemy: filter by date for an datetime field (does not work with SQLite, with PostgreSQL it works fine)

Comment: I wonder what happends with the first and last records?

Answer (score 0):

```
# previous
prv = select([images.c.id, images.c.name]).where(images.c.id < id).order_by(images.c.id.desc()).limit(1)
res = engine.connect().execute(prv)
for res in res:
    print(res.id, res.name)

# next
nxt = select([images.c.id, images.c.name]).where(images.c.id > id).order_by(images.c.id).limit(1)
res = engine.connect().execute(nxt)
for res in res:
    print(res.id, res.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in a "single" query by taking the `UNION` of two queries, one to select the previous and target records and one to select the next record (unless the backend is SQLite, which does not permit an `ORDER BY`  before the final statement in a `UNION`):

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
with engine.connect() as conn:
    target = 3
    query1 = sa.select(tbl).where(tbl.c.id <= target).order_by(tbl.c.id.desc()).limit(2)
    query2 = sa.select(tbl).where(tbl.c.id > target).order_by(tbl.c.id.asc()).limit(1)
    res = conn.execute(query1.union(query2))
    for row in res:
        print(row)
```

producing

```
(2, 'b.jpg')
(3, 'c.jpg')
(4, 'd.jpg')
```

Note that we could make the second query the same as the first, apart from reversing the inequality

```py
query2 = sa.select(tbl).where(tbl.c.id >= target).order_by(tbl.c.id.asc()).limit(2)
```

and we would get the same result as the union would remove the duplicate target row.

---

If the requirement were to find the surrounding rows for a selection of rows we could use the `lag` and `lead` window functions, if they are supported.

```py
# Works in PostgreSQL, MariaDB and SQLite, at least.

with engine.connect() as conn:
    query = sa.select(
        tbl.c.id,
        tbl.c.name,
        sa.func.lag(tbl.c.name).over(order_by=tbl.c.id).label('prev'),
        sa.func.lead(tbl.c.name).over(order_by=tbl.c.id).label('next'),
    )
    res = conn.execute(query)
    for row in res:
        print(row._mapping)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'a.jpg', 'prev': None, 'next': 'b.jpg'}
{'id': 2, 'name': 'b.jpg', 'prev': 'a.jpg', 'next': 'c.jpg'}
{'id': 3, 'name': 'c.jpg', 'prev': 'b.jpg', 'next': 'd.jpg'}
{'id': 4, 'name': 'd.jpg', 'prev': 'c.jpg', 'next': 'e.jpg'}
{'id': 5, 'name': 'e.jpg', 'prev': 'd.jpg', 'next': 'f.jpg'}
{'id': 6, 'name': 'f.jpg', 'prev': 'e.jpg', 'next': None}
```

Answer (score -6):

To iterate through your records. I think that this is what you're looking for.

```
for row in res:
  print row.id
  print row.name
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked about. Also his example queries for a single record, not a collection of records.